# How to return the higher value of two cards?

Tags: python-3.x, playing-cards

I am creating a deck of cards and have to complete certain tasks. The third task asks me to compare two cards: `card1` and `card2`. The function should return `1` if `card1` is greater than `card2`, `2` if `card2` is greater than `card1`, or `0` if both cards are equal. Suits should be ignored. The output is incorrect. For `hand_1`, 1 is returned when 0 should be returned. For `hand_2`, 2 is returned which is correct. For `hand_3`, 2 is returned when 1 should be returned. My question is: how do I make it so that 0, 1, and 2 are returned correctly? I have provided the entire code (Task 3 is at the bottom). Note that I cannot change the code that was provided to me, so I have to work with this code.

---

```
#Task 1
#------

import random

diamonds = ['2♦','3♦','4♦','5♦','6♦','7♦','8♦','9♦','10♦','J♦','Q♦','K♦','A♦']
clubs = ['2♣','3♣','4♣','5♣','6♣','7♣','8♣','9♣','10♣','J♣','Q♣','K♣','A♣']
hearts = ['2♥','3♥','4♥','5♥','6♥','7♥','8♥','9♥','10♥','J♥','Q♥','K♥','A♥']
spades = ['2♠','3♠','4♠','5♠','6♠','7♠','8♠','9♠','10♠','J♠','Q♠','K♠','A♠']

def shuffled_deck():
    """
    Shuffles the deck of cards and returns a shuffled deck.
    """
    deck = diamonds + clubs + hearts + spades
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

deck = shuffled_deck()

if (len(deck) == 52):
    print("You might have created a random deck!")
    print(deck)
else:
    print("Your deck isn't yet complete.")
    print(deck)

#Task 2
#------

def deal_N_cards(deck, N):
    """
    Returns a list of N cards and removes them from the deck.
    """
    return [deck.pop() for k in range(N)]   

deck2 = shuffled_deck()
hand1 = deal_N_cards(deck2, 5)
hand2 = deal_N_cards(deck2, 5)
hand3 = deal_N_cards(deck2, 20)

if (len(hand1) + len(hand2) + len(hand3) + len(deck2) == 52):
    print()
    print("You might have completed task 2!")
    print("hand1:")
    print(hand1)
    print("hand2:")
    print(hand2)
    print("hand3:")
    print(hand3)
    print("deck2:")
    print(deck2)
else:
    print()
    print("Your function isn't yet complete.")
    print("hand1:")
    print(hand1)
    print("hand2:")
    print(hand2)
    print("hand3:")
    print(hand3)
    print("deck2:")
    print(deck2)

#Task 3
#------

def compare_cards(card1, card2):
    """
    Returns 1 if the value of card1 is greater,
    2 if the value of card2 is greater,
    or 0 if the values of both card1 and card2 are equal.
    """
    'A' == 11
    'K' == 10
    'Q' == 10
    'J' == 10
    if card1 > card2:
        return 1
    if card1 < card2:
        return 2
    if card1 == card2:
        return 0

deck3 = shuffled_deck()
hand_1 = compare_cards('4♣', '4♠')
hand_2 = compare_cards('2♠', '6♣')
hand_3 = compare_cards('A♣', 'K♠')

print()
print("You might have completed task 3!")
print("Hand 1:")
print(hand_1)
print("Hand 2:")
print(hand_2)
print("Hand 3:")
print(hand_3)
```

Answer (score 1):

'Strings are compared lexicographically, and dissimilar types are compared by the name of their type ("int" < "string"). 3.x fixes the second point by making them non-comparable.'Basically your comparing a string using mathematic logic which won't work.

As for how to fix this I think you need to restructure how your deck is made.
You could do this either by making a dictionary where the key is the suit and value is value.
Or you could have a list of lists with the suit being the name of each list. But overall the way you have structured your code needs a more object orientated approach. Such as your deck being an object with various functions attached to it instead of you creating a second deck.